# How to use maths to optimize hydro turbines?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

I need to prove that for a given total power produced by $n$ turbines, the best power production distribution between the turbines is the even distribution.

All the turbines have the same $\eta = f(P)$ curve.
Here is an example of a curve:

[image: Efficiency function of the power for one turbine]

This function is known to be concave ($f'$ is decreasing, $f''$ is less than or equal to zero).
How can I prove that for a given number of active turbines, the most efficient power production distribution between the turbines is the even distribution?

I tried to prove with the axioms

$f'$ is decreasing

$f'' \leq 0$

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} P_i = P_{total}$

that

$max \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(P_i)$ is obtained for $P_1 = ... = P_n$

but didn't succeed.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Did you try Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: What is an "even distribution"? Did you mean *uniform*?

Answer (score 0):

Assume there are indices $i$ and $j$ such that $P_i\neq P_j.$ Now we create a new configuration $P^{\star}_1,\ldots,P^{\star}_n$ with $P^{\star}_k = P_k$ for $k\not\in\{i,j\}$ and $P^{\star}_i=P^{\star}_j = \frac{1}{2}(P_i+P_j).$
Then $\sum_{k=1}^n P^{\star}_k = \sum_{k=1}^n P_k= P_{total}$ and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n f(P^{\star}_k) - \sum_{k=1}^n f(P_k) 
= 2\left( f\left(\frac{1}{2}(P_i+P_j)\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(f(P_i)+f(P_j)\right)\right) > 0
$$
because $f$ is concave. In other words, if the $P_i$ are not all the same, you can obtain a better configuration simply by moving two of them towards their arithmetic mean. This is turn means that all $P_i$ must be the same in the optimal configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already proved that for a power lower and a power greater than the mean the efficiency is lower but what I try to find is a proof for every case (i.e. There is no equal power production among the turbines). Because I can prove it is true for special cases, but there are so many of them it is a lost cause to prove it through it.

Comment: @GZR What is missing? I have shown that if there are at least two values $P_i$ and $P_j$ that are not the same, then this cannot be the optimal distribution, because you can easily find a better one in this case. Therefore, the optimal distribution must be the one in which all $P_i$ attain the same value. Isn't this exactly what you wanted to show?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f(p) = \max(0,f_0-(p-p_0)^2)$ then the problem can be stated as

$$
\max \sum_{k=1}^nf(p_k)\ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \sum_{k=1}^n p_k = P
$$

and the corresponding lagrangian

$$
L(p_1,\cdots,p_k,\cdots,p_n,\lambda) = \sum_{k=1}^nf(p_k)+\lambda \left(\sum_{k=1}^n p_k - P\right)
$$

with stationary points at the solutions of

$$
\nabla L = \cases{2(p_k-p_0)+\lambda = 0, k=1,\cdots, n\\ \sum_{k=1}^n p_k - P=0}
$$

or at $p_k = p_0-\frac{\lambda}{2}$, then $n\left(p_0-\frac{\lambda}{2}\right)=P$ or $\lambda = 2\left(p_0-\frac P2\right)$. Now knowing $\lambda$ we follow with

$$
2(p_k-p_0)+2\left(p_0-\frac Pn\right) = 0\Rightarrow p_k = \frac Pn
$$